# Hadoop and httpfs Installation difficulties

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop in my VM, and I can visit using :

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/
```

But when I tried to visit from another VM using:

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://hadoop-vm:9000/
```

I received a 'connection refused error'.

In the browser I can visit:

```
http://hadoop-vm:50090 etc
```

Can anyone tell me how to enable a visit from another vm using `hdfs`?

Another question is I can not install Hadoop `httpfs`, and I can not find out any info how to download it at all. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please split separate questions into separate posts.

Answer (score 0):

-sounds like a firewall or something is blocking access to port 9000. Try to telnet to it both in the VM and remotely.
-otherwise, look at the http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused hints
-don't worry about httpfs.